# Amazon SNS sends message to an Amazon SQS queue but not the other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have 2 Amazon SQS queues subscribed to the same Amazon SNS topic. All 3 resources are in the same AWS account.

One of the SQS queues receives messages from the SNS topic but the other SQS queue never does.

I checked that the SQS access policies are exactly the same.

What are some ideas to debug the issue?

Comment: Do you have any consumers attached to the SQS queues (eg Lambda functions)? I'm just wondering if the message is consumed, so you don't actually see it in the queue. Have you tried creating _another_ SQS queue and subscribing it to the SNS topic, just to see what happens?

Comment: There is a lambda attached to the sqs that doesnt receive messages but the logs to the lambda dont show any activity. Yes I have created another SQS queue and subscribed it to the SNS topic and it does recieve msgs. Could it be something to to with IAM policies/permissions tied to the SQS? How would I check those?

Comment: I would suggest that you temporarily disconnect the AWS Lambda function and confirm that messages are getting to the queue. Then, reattach the lambda function and check the Lambda logs to see whether the function is executing. Make sure the Lambda function has the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy attached to its IAM Role, which allows it to send messages to CloudWatch Logs.